# Starting a new line based on a specific string

Tags: linux, text-processing, text-formatting

I need to start a new line based on a specific string and add the lines between those strings onto the same line.

Input:

```
Gator_locus100 

AGTCGTGTAGATGATAGTCGATGATGGATGANNNNGTACGT
GCTCAGTCGTGCTCGTCGATCGATCGTCAGCTCGATCGATCGATCGATCGACTCGATCG
GCTCGATCGATCGATC

Gator_locus101

ATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGAT
GCAGTCGATCGATACGATCGATACGACTACGA
TCGATCGATCGCATCGATCGATCGACTC

Gator_locus102
NNNNNNNNNGCTCAGTCGATCGATCGCATCGATCGACTACGTACGATCGATCAGCATCAG
GCTCAGTCGTGCTCGTCGATCGATCGTCAGCTCGATCGATCGATCGATCGACTCGATCG
GACTCAGATCGATGACTACGATCAGATCGATAACGATCAGTACGACTACGATCAGCATCAGAT
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGACTACGACATCGATCAGACTCAGACGT
```

Ouput:

```
Gator_locus100  AGTCGTGTAGATGATAGTCGATGATGGATGANNNNGTACGTGCTCAGTC....

Gator_locus101 ATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGCGATGCAGTCGATCGATACGATCGATACG....

Gator_locus102 NNNNNNNNNGCTCAGTCGATCGATCGCATCGATCGACTACGTACGATC .....
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk -v ORS= '/Gator_/{ if (NR > 1) print RS RS }1; END{ print RS }' file
```

The output:

```
Gator_locus100 AGTCGTGTAGATGATAGTCGATGATGGATGANNNNGTACGTGCTCAGTCGTGCTCGTCGATCGATCGTCAGCTCGATCGATCGATCGATCGACTCGATCGGCTCGATCGATCGATC

Gator_locus101ATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATGCAGTCGATCGATACGATCGATACGACTACGATCGATCGATCGCATCGATCGATCGACTC

Gator_locus102NNNNNNNNNGCTCAGTCGATCGATCGCATCGATCGACTACGTACGATCGATCAGCATCAGGCTCAGTCGTGCTCGTCGATCGATCGTCAGCTCGATCGATCGATCGATCGACTCGATCGGACTCAGATCGATGACTACGATCAGATCGATAACGATCAGTACGACTACGATCAGCATCAGATNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGACTACGACATCGATCAGACTCAGACGT
```

Comment: How would you add a comma or some other type of field delimiter between Gator_locus*** and the sequence?

Comment: @Josh, `awk -v ORS= '/Gator_/{ $0=$0","; if (NR > 1) print RS RS }1; END{ print RS }' file`